# Rest Assured - 404 when accessing localhost but accessible using Postman and browser

Tags: rest-assured

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErQ6e.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZlPI.png)I get 404 when testing a GET api using Rest Assured on localhost developed using Spring boot Data JPA. However, On clicking the request url from Rest Assured logs it opens in browser.
The request works fine on Postman as well. However, cUrl code generated by Postman throws same error.

For Post request I get 403, Forbidden error in RA. works fine in Postman.

[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshot to confirm it works fine on postman?

Comment: Attached snapshot to show it works on Postman. The curl code generated by Postman throws 404 as well - Snapshot attached

Comment: Add `user-agent` may fix your problem. Try add other headers that postman automatically added.

Comment: I have tried adding all the headers shown in postman including user-agent but same issue. In fact, curl automatically sends user-agent and can be seen with -v. I think this issue is only on mac os